# Does Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection support framework 4.5.1 or not?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, owin

This article (http://scottdorman.github.io/2016/03/17/integrating-asp.net-core-dependency-injection-in-mvc-4/) states the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection package supports framework 4.5.1 (which we are using). However, when I try to install the nuget package I get an error saying that it doesn't support 4.5.1.

What gives?

[image: Installation Fails]

Comment: 1 note, 4.5.1 is dead, target as 4.5.2, but the new version of your packages targets for .net standard 2.0 so you need .net 4.6.1 or better 4.7.1

Answer (score 1):

Ok, apparently it no longer supports 4.5.1 but an earlier version does so I installed version 1.1.1.

Can run the following in package manager:
Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection -Version 1.1.1

Comment: I tried to download the version you specified, but it's not downloading.
Got this error ->
The element 'metadata' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd' has invalid child element 'serviceable' in namespace 
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd'. List of possible elements expected: 'references, title, iconUrl, summary, licenseUrl, language, copyright, 
projectUrl, releaseNotes, dependencies, frameworkAssemblies' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd'.

Comment: @Gururaj This probably isn't helpful, but even though I got it to work at the time I still ended up deciding to go with a different DI container. I think I ended up settling on Autofac after trying that one and a couple others.